# .msg file gives download error

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, http-status-code-404

In my application, I keep some files on server and make them available for download on some business logic.

All other file types are getting downloaded but `.msg(Outlook message)` file do not get downloaded and gives Error:

```
404 - File or directory not found. The resource you are looking for might
have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Images, .docx, .txt all other files are working well.

The page is designed in ASP.NET and at client site following mark up comes.

Comment: <td>
 <a href="../Upload/Bugs/34238/117722/Error logging hours in PT.msg" target="_blank">
  Error logging hours in PT.msg
 </a>
 ,
 <a href="../Upload/Bugs/34238/117722/PhotoShare.png" target="_blank">
  PhotoShare.png
 </a>
</td>

Comment: above is the code which comes in output

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Found on ASP.NET [forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1468840.aspx/1).

Create a handler, download it as a file:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-outlook";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=Message.msg");
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(YourPathToMsgFile));
Response.End();
```

or change the setting in IIS 6.0:

> Select HTTP Header -> click MIME types - > Click New and add ".msg" as extension and "application/vnd.ms-outlook" as MIME type.

Comment: In IIS 7.5, click on the server, then in the IIS section choose "Mime Types", then click "Add..." under the actions bar on the right (or right click in the list of mime types).

Answer (score 7):

using this tag below we can directly mention the file name to the  tag.

```
   <a href="Your File_Location">Download Link</a>
```

no need to specify the code in the controller.

just add below tag to web.config inside

```
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".msg" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
</staticContent>
```

Comment: Please edit your answer, and explain why this solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
<system.webServer>   
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".msg" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the another response that I found on ASP.NET Forum. Included here to as time saver.

If ASP.NET Core is handling the static content itself and is running at the edge, or if you need ASP.NET Core to be aware of mime types, you need to configure ASP.NET Core's handler to be aware of it using FileExtensionContentTypeProvider like below :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // Set up custom content types - associating file extension to MIME type
    var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
    // Replace an existing mapping
    provider.Mappings[".msg"] = "application/vnd.ms-outlook";

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "images")),
        RequestPath = "/StaticContentDir",
        ContentTypeProvider = provider
    });
```

Credits Sherry Chan

[ASPNET Forum LINK](https://forums.asp.net/t/2154710.aspx?App%20Migration%20to%20NET%20Core%20and%20msg%20files)

Comment: My dearest friend Avi, your aswer is completely right but there is a catch. In production (IIS 10 at least) the function Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() returned "c:\windows\system32\inetsrv" wich resulted in an error. Even though the documentation cites this exacly code.

I've changed this line to "Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, "images")" and then everything worked just fine in production.

Thanks for your help.