# Blazor server app cannot download .msg files

Tags: iis, blazor-server-side, mime-types

I have a Blazor Server 6.0 app where I have links to download .msg files.

I have setup IIS to serve that mime-type trying both application/octet-stream and application/vnd.ms-outlook (and restarting IIS)

I have also tried to put in web.config the staticcontent tag like suggested here:
[.msg file gives download error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718003/msg-file-gives-download-error)

And obviously in my program.cs I have app.UseStaticFiles();

I try to put the .msg in a non-blazor app and they work ok, so I think is not IIS related

So why I cannot download (or open automatically in outlook) this type of file, while other (docx, pdf, zip, etc.) are Ok ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Core -- on the server side -- also needs to know about the files it has to serve. You can enable serving all unknown file types (I'd rather not include the relevant code as it is a major security risk), or you can add you own additional mappings like so:

```cs
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings[".msg"] = "application/vnd.ms-outlook";

// app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
});
```

More info in the official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#fileextensioncontenttypeprovider

---

Additionally, Blazor Server registers custom options for serving static files (like `.server.js`, which is different from just `.js`). It's not directly exposed as a public API to configure, but you can look at the source [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/4afa32bfe08a6b42f89a469b250ebdef403b6bb3/src/Components/Server/src/DependencyInjection/ComponentServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L61) as to what the `AddServerSideBlazor` extension method actually does. The solution there relies on you calling `UseStaticFiles` **without explicitly specifying the options**, so that it can retrieve the `StaticFilesOptions` instance from DI.

Armed with this knowledge, you can override an already configured options instance as follows:

```cs
builder.Services.PostConfigure<StaticFileOptions>(o =>
{
    ((FileExtensionContentTypeProvider)o.ContentTypeProvider).Mappings[".msg"] = "application/vnd.ms-outlook";
});
```

This configures the already initialized options instance registered in the DI (after all other configurations happened on it, thus `PostConfigure`).

Note that if you would for whatever reason decide to use a different `IContentTypeProvider`, the unsafe cast above would need to be revised as well.

Comment: Doing so, it deny the use of .js file and the blazor.server.js is not loaded.

Comment: I'm not sure what you did exactly, but if you only did the modifications I wrote, it should be working. I tried on a new empty Blazor Server project (which doesn't serve .msg files by default), and after configuring the MIME type correctly, it works (with and without IIS [Express]). That is because the `FileExtensionContentTypeProvider` has `.js` and many other file types preconfigured.

Comment: Mine (new blazor server app .net6) doesn't work neither...  Same error if I press F12

Did you try to navigate to Counter Page e see if the increment button works?

Comment: Now I see your problem, yes. I'll update the answer with additional info.